# Groovy not matching left braces in regex

Tags: regex, groovy

Groovy 2.4 here. I have a list of characters I'd like to match, specifically:

> `;[]&<>?:()|

My best attempt:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

Matcher matcher
String illNameChars = /[`\/;\[\]&<>?:\()|-]+/
String input = "Bupo;dupo"
if(input) {
    matcher = input =~ illNameChars
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        println "Illegal character detected!"
    }
}
```

This works for the first character (the backtick "`") and the second character (";"), but not the third character ("[")...any ideas as to why?

Comment: Since it's not a string, just escape the right bracket `/[\`;[\]&<>?:()|]+/` The rules of character class parsing are a little different, metacharacters are literal except for the `]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double escaping the braces:

Try:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

String input = "["
Matcher matcher = input =~ /[`\/;\[\]&<>?:\()|-]+/
if(matcher.matches()) {
    println "Matched!"
} else {
    println "No match!"
}
```

Notice only one escape for the [ and ] characters. This resulted in a match when I ran it.

Comment: Note that `(` does not have to be escaped at all inside a character class.

Comment: Thanks @cjstehno (+1) - can you please see my edits, any clue as to why your regex isn't working there? Thanks!

Comment: The answer on your other question addressed this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37149584/1073826