# Groovy matcher.matches does not seem to be working for valid regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I asked a similar question earlier, but I'm not using a different part of the Groovy/Java 8 regex/pattern/matcher API.

Groovy 2.4 here:

```
class TestPatterns {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher
        String illNameChars = /[`\/;\[\]&<>?:\()|-]+/
        String input = "Bupo`dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo/dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo;dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo[dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo]dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo&dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo<dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo>dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo?dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo:dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo\\dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo(dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo)dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo|dupo"
//        String input = "Bupo-dupo"
        if(input) {
            matcher = input =~ illNameChars
            if(matcher.matches()) {
                println "Illegal character detected!"
            } else {
                println "The input is perfectly legal."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this print out "*The input is perfectly legal.*"? The `input` string clearly has a backtick in it and this is defined in the regex. Am I using `matcher.matches()` incorrectly?

Ultimately, I want the following characters to be considered "illegal":

> `/;[]&<>?:()|-

But the code above seems to fail for all the `input` permutations, regardless of which one I have "toggled on" (not commented out). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Matcher.matches()`, the whole input must "match" the regex, so you would have to change your regex to be `` /.*[`\/;\[\]&<>?:\()|-].*/ ``.

Alternatively to creating the Matcher object with `=~` and then using its method, you can also simply use the `==~` matches operator. (`if (input ==~ illNameChars) ...`).

Alternatively you can also just do `if (matcher) ...` after you created it with `=~`.

The last alternative you have is to keep your regex as it is, but use `if (matcher.find()) ...` instead, as `find()` checks whether the regex matches any substring of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

As in Java, the `.matches()` method only returns `True` if the entire input string matches the regex.

Since you already used the `=~` operator to create a matcher object, just test for `if matcher` (as shown [in the docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_find_operator)).